# Kibana, Elasticsearch, APM with docker-compose

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose, kibana, apm

Here my detail question : [Open Link](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/kibana-elasticsearch-apm-with-docker-compose/354798/1)

Kibana version: 8.12.2
Elasticsearch version: 8.12.2
APM Server version: 8.12.2
Use : docker

Hello im install kibana, elasticsearch, apm with 1 docker-compose file:

```
version: "2.2"

services:
  setup:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:${STACK_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - certs:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs
    user: "0"
    command: >
      bash -c '
        if [ x${ELASTIC_PASSWORD} == x ]; then
          echo "Set the ELASTIC_PASSWORD environment variable in the .env file";
          exit 1;
        elif [ x${KIBANA_PASSWORD} == x ]; then
          echo "Set the KIBANA_PASSWORD environment variable in the .env file";
          exit 1;
        fi;
        if [ ! -f config/certs/ca.zip ]; then
          echo "Creating CA";
          bin/elasticsearch-certutil ca --silent --pem -out config/certs/ca.zip;
          unzip config/certs/ca.zip -d config/certs;
        fi;
        if [ ! -f config/certs/certs.zip ]; then
          echo "Creating certs";
          echo -ne \
          "instances:\n"\
          "  - name: es01\n"\
          "    dns:\n"\
          "      - es01\n"\
          "      - localhost\n"\
          "    ip:\n"\
          "      - 127.0.0.1\n"\
          "  - name: es02\n"\
          "    dns:\n"\
          "      - es02\n"\
          "      - localhost\n"\
          "    ip:\n"\
          "      - 127.0.0.1\n"\
          > config/certs/instances.yml;
          bin/elasticsearch-certutil cert --silent --pem -out config/certs/certs.zip --in config/certs/instances.yml --ca-cert config/certs/ca/ca.crt --ca-key config/certs/ca/ca.key;
          unzip config/certs/certs.zip -d config/certs;
        fi;
        echo "Setting file permissions"
        chown -R root:root config/certs;
        find . -type d -exec chmod 750 \{\} \;;
        find . -type f -exec chmod 640 \{\} \;;
        echo "Waiting for Elasticsearch availability";
        until curl -s --cacert config/certs/ca/ca.crt https://es01:9200 | grep -q "missing authentication credentials"; do sleep 30; done;
        echo "Setting kibana_system password";
        until curl -s -X POST --cacert config/certs/ca/ca.crt -u "elastic:${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://es01:9200/_security/user/kibana_system/_password -d "{\"password\":\"${KIBANA_PASSWORD}\"}" | grep -q "^{}"; do sleep 10; done;
        echo "All done!";
      '
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "[ -f config/certs/es01/es01.crt ]"]
      interval: 1s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 120

  es01:
    depends_on:
      setup:
        condition: service_healthy
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:${STACK_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - certs:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs
      - esdata01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - ${ES_PORT}:9200
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - cluster.name=${CLUSTER_NAME}
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es02
      - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - xpack.security.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.key=certs/es01/es01.key
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate=certs/es01/es01.crt
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities=certs/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.key=certs/es01/es01.key
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate=certs/es01/es01.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities=certs/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode=certificate
      - xpack.license.self_generated.type=${LICENSE}
    mem_limit: ${MEM_LIMIT}
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          "curl -s --cacert config/certs/ca/ca.crt https://localhost:9200 | grep -q 'missing authentication credentials'",
        ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 120

  es02:
    depends_on:
      - es01
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:${STACK_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - certs:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs
      - esdata02:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    environment:
      - node.name=es02
      - cluster.name=${CLUSTER_NAME}
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - xpack.security.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.key=certs/es02/es02.key
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate=certs/es02/es02.crt
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities=certs/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.key=certs/es02/es02.key
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate=certs/es02/es02.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities=certs/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode=certificate
      - xpack.license.self_generated.type=${LICENSE}
    mem_limit: ${MEM_LIMIT}
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          "curl -s --cacert config/certs/ca/ca.crt https://localhost:9200 | grep -q 'missing authentication credentials'",
        ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 120

  apm:
    depends_on:
      es01:
        condition: service_healthy
    image: docker.elastic.co/apm/apm-server:${STACK_VERSION}
    ports:
      - ${APM_SERVER_PORT}:8200
    volumes:
      - "./apm-server.docker.yml:/usr/share/apm-server/apm-server.yml:ro"

  kibana:
    depends_on:
      es01:
        condition: service_healthy
      es02:
        condition: service_healthy
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:${STACK_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - certs:/usr/share/kibana/config/certs
      - kibanadata:/usr/share/kibana/data
    ports:
      - ${KIBANA_PORT}:5601
    environment:
      - SERVERNAME=kibana
      - SERVER_PUBLICBASEURL
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=https://es01:9200
      - ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=kibana_system
      - ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=${KIBANA_PASSWORD}
      - ELASTICSEARCH_SSL_CERTIFICATEAUTHORITIES=config/certs/ca/ca.crt
    mem_limit: ${MEM_LIMIT}
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          "curl -s -I http://localhost:5601 | grep -q 'HTTP/1.1 302 Found'",
        ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 120

volumes:
  certs:
    driver: local
  esdata01:
    driver: local
  esdata02:
    driver: local
  kibanadata:
    driver: local
```

and this my `apm-server-docker.yml`

```
apm-server:
  host: "0.0.0.0:8200"
output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["es01:9200"]
  ssl.verification_mode: none
  username: "elastic"
  api_key: "xxxx"
```

API Key already create in this page, and set in that APM configuration, the Elastic APM Integrations already installedm and APM server & Agent status also is correct setup

This log i get in APM Server:

```
{"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2024-03-06T05:33:19.847Z","log.logger":"beater","log.origin":{"function":"github.com/elastic/apm-server/internal/beater.waitReady","file.name":"beater/waitready.go","file.line":64},"message":"precondition failed: EOF","service.name":"apm-server","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
{"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2024-03-06T05:33:28.643Z","log.logger":"agentcfg","log.origin":{"function":"github.com/elastic/apm-server/internal/agentcfg.(*ElasticsearchFetcher).Run.func1","file.name":"agentcfg/elasticsearch.go","file.line":150},"message":"refresh cache error: context deadline exceeded","service.name":"apm-server","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
{"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2024-03-06T05:33:34.857Z","log.logger":"beater","log.origin":{"function":"github.com/elastic/apm-server/internal/beater.waitReady","file.name":"beater/waitready.go","file.line":64},"message":"precondition failed: EOF","service.name":"apm-server","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
{"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2024-03-06T05:33:40.141Z","log.logger":"request","log.origin":{"function":"github.com/elastic/apm-server/internal/beater/api.apmMiddleware.LogMiddleware.func1.1","file.name":"middleware/log_middleware.go","file.line":58},"message":"request timed out","service.name":"apm-server","url.original":"/intake/v2/events","http.request.method":"POST","user_agent.original":"elastic-apm-ruby/4.7.0 (app-social-bot)","source.address":"3.22.132.134","http.request.id":"79216b13-cd04-4d3c-9026-179a556f0d8e","event.duration":60002369231,"http.response.status_code":503,"error.message":"request timed out","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
{"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2024-03-06T05:33:49.870Z","log.logger":"beater","log.origin":{"function":"github.com/elastic/apm-server/internal/beater.waitReady","file.name":"beater/waitready.go","file.line":64},"message":"precondition failed: EOF","service.name":"apm-server","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
{"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2024-03-06T05:33:58.644Z","log.logger":"agentcfg","log.origin":{"function":"github.com/elastic/apm-server/internal/agentcfg.(*ElasticsearchFetcher).Run.func1","file.name":"agentcfg/elasticsearch.go","file.line":150},"message":"refresh cache error: context deadline exceeded","service.name":"apm-server","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
{"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2024-03-06T05:34:04.879Z","log.logger":"beater","log.origin":{"function":"github.com/elastic/apm-server/internal/beater.waitReady","file.name":"beater/waitready.go","file.line":64},"message":"precondition failed: EOF","service.name":"apm-server","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
{"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2024-03-06T05:34:06.686Z","log.logger":"request","log.origin":{"function":"github.com/elastic/apm-server/internal/beater/api.apmMiddleware.LogMiddleware.func1.1","file.name":"middleware/log_middleware.go","file.line":58},"message":"request timed out","service.name":"apm-server","url.original":"/intake/v2/events","http.request.method":"POST","user_agent.original":"elastic-apm-ruby/4.7.0 (app-social-bot)","source.address":"3.22.132.134","http.request.id":"67f9c4a8-2432-4517-8777-9adc814d666f","event.duration":47736534558,"http.response.status_code":503,"error.message":"request timed out","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
{"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2024-03-06T05:34:10.150Z","log.logger":"request","log.origin":{"function":"github.com/elastic/apm-server/internal/beater/api.apmMiddleware.LogMiddleware.func1.1","file.name":"middleware/log_middleware.go","file.line":58},"message":"request timed out","service.name":"apm-server","url.original":"/intake/v2/events","http.request.method":"POST","user_agent.original":"elastic-apm-ruby/4.7.0 (app-social-bot)","source.address":"3.22.132.134","http.request.id":"7cfca566-200b-4392-8494-e1ff961d1d4d","event.duration":60002456663,"http.response.status_code":503,"error.message":"request timed out","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
{"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2024-03-06T05:34:19.887Z","log.logger":"beater","log.origin":{"function":"github.com/elastic/apm-server/internal/beater.waitReady","file.name":"beater/waitready.go","file.line":64},"message":"precondition failed: EOF","service.name":"apm-server","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
{"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2024-03-06T05:34:28.643Z","log.logger":"agentcfg","log.origin":{"function":"github.com/elastic/apm-server/internal/agentcfg.(*ElasticsearchFetcher).Run.func1","file.name":"agentcfg/elasticsearch.go","file.line":150},"message":"refresh cache error: context deadline exceeded","service.name":"apm-server","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
{"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2024-03-06T05:34:34.669Z","log.logger":"request","log.origin":{"function":"github.com/elastic/apm-server/internal/beater/api.apmMiddleware.LogMiddleware.func1.1","file.name":"middleware/log_middleware.go","file.line":58},"message":"request timed out","service.name":"apm-server","url.original":"/intake/v2/events","http.request.method":"POST","user_agent.original":"elastic-apm-ruby/4.7.0 (app-social-bot)","source.address":"3.22.132.134","http.request.id":"987d9e0a-86b6-45d9-9b90-7370a3d98c34","event.duration":27391056678,"http.response.status_code":503,"error.message":"request timed out","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
{"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2024-03-06T05:34:34.705Z","log.logger":"request","log.origin":{"function":"github.com/elastic/apm-server/internal/beater/api.apmMiddleware.LogMiddleware.func1.1","file.name":"middleware/log_middleware.go","file.line":58},"message":"request timed out","service.name":"apm-server","url.original":"/intake/v2/events","http.request.method":"POST","user_agent.original":"elastic-apm-ruby/4.7.0 (app-social-bot)","source.address":"3.22.132.134","http.request.id":"b31875c0-7648-4c32-85a1-26247207559c","event.duration":44734158601,"http.response.status_code":503,"error.message":"request timed out","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
{"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2024-03-06T05:34:34.900Z","log.logger":"beater","log.origin":{"function":"github.com/elastic/apm-server/internal/beater.waitReady","file.name":"beater/waitready.go","file.line":64},"message":"precondition failed: EOF","service.name":"apm-server","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
{"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2024-03-06T05:34:40.143Z","log.logger":"request","log.origin":{"function":"github.com/elastic/apm-server/internal/beater/api.apmMiddleware.LogMiddleware.func1.1","file.name":"middleware/log_middleware.go","file.line":58},"message":"request timed out","service.name":"apm-server","url.original":"/intake/v2/events","http.request.method":"POST","user_agent.original":"elastic-apm-ruby/4.7.0 (app-social-bot)","source.address":"3.22.132.134","http.request.id":"7776a2da-70d4-47d0-97a0-5353a40c1b3a","event.duration":60000197712,"http.response.status_code":503,"error.message":"request timed out","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
{"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2024-03-06T05:34:44.923Z","log.logger":"request","log.origin":{"function":"github.com/elastic/apm-server/internal/beater/api.apmMiddleware.LogMiddleware.func1.1","file.name":"middleware/log_middleware.go","file.line":58},"message":"request timed out","service.name":"apm-server","url.original":"/intake/v2/events","http.request.method":"POST","user_agent.original":"elastic-apm-ruby/4.7.0 (app-social-bot)","source.address":"3.22.132.134","http.request.id":"91efe4f9-deab-40e4-aef3-69d817f45a15","event.duration":43633899498,"http.response.status_code":503,"error.message":"request timed out","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
{"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2024-03-06T05:34:49.918Z","log.logger":"beater","log.origin":{"function":"github.com/elastic/apm-server/internal/beater.waitReady","file.name":"beater/waitready.go","file.line":64},"message":"precondition failed: EOF","service.name":"apm-server","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
{"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2024-03-06T05:34:58.644Z","log.logger":"agentcfg","log.origin":{"function":"github.com/elastic/apm-server/internal/agentcfg.(*ElasticsearchFetcher).Run.func1","file.name":"agentcfg/elasticsearch.go","file.line":150},"message":"refresh cache error: context deadline exceeded","service.name":"apm-server","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
```

Always get error 503,
Im already trying to ping inside container APM server to es01 and that work.

Maybe i have wrong on my docker-compose.yml file ?

My APM Server can connect to my elastic and kibana, and my APM agent in my service can send a log to my APM Server

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 503 signifies Queue is full.

Please read more [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/server/current/common-problems.html#queue-full) on elasticsearch common problems webpage.